# unable to read modbus data using jamod 2( wimpi.modbus )

Tags: java, modbus

i am new to java serial port programming​,

I have trying to read data from the modbus slave device through modbus RTU over serial port from my java application.

I am using the Jamod java library to read modbus protocal.

In my case my application failed to receive entire modbus response from the device. please find my java coding and error log for your reference.

Any one can suggest me what may be the reason for the error.

```
<br/>

**ERROR**<br/>
 Clear input: 02 c2 c1<br/>
 Sent: 01 04 03 e8 00 05 b0 79 <br/>
 Last request: 01 04 03 e8 00 05 b0 79<br/>
 CRC Error in received frame: 0 bytes: <br/>
 Response: 01 84 <br/>
 net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusIOException: I/O exception - failed to read<br/>
 at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusRTUTransport.readResponse(ModbusRTUTransport.java:163)<br/>
 at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusSerialTransaction.execute(ModbusSerialTransaction.java:187)<br/>
 at modbusnewapplication.ModbusConnection.main(ModbusConnection.java:8<br/>


Modbus Program <br/>
---------------<br/>

package modbusnewapplication;<br/>

import java.io.;<br/>
import javax.comm.;<br/>
import net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusCoupler;<br/>
import net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusSerialTransaction;<br/>
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadInputRegistersRequest;<br/>
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadInputRegistersResponse;<br/>
import net.wimpi.modbus.net.SerialConnection;<br/>
import net.wimpi.modbus.util.SerialParameters;<br/>

public class ModbusConnection {<br/>

public static void main(String[] args) {<br/>

// if (args.length < 4) {<br/>
// System.out.println("not enough args");<br/>
// System.exit(1);<br/>
// }else{<br/>
try {<br/>

    System.out.println("Serial Port Connection");<br/><br/>
    /* The important instances of the classes mentioned before */<br/>
    SerialConnection con = null; //the connection<br/>
    ModbusSerialTransaction trans = null; //the transaction<br/>
    ReadInputRegistersRequest req = null; //the request<br/>
    ReadInputRegistersResponse res = null; //the response<br/>

     // **1 Variables for storing the parameters** <br/>
     String portname= "COM1"; //the name of the serial port to be used<br/>
     int unitid = 1; //the unit identifier we will be talking to<br/>
     int ref = 1000; //the reference, where to start reading from<br/>
     int count = 5; //the count of IR's to read<br/>
     int repeat = 1; //a loop for repeating the transaction  <br/>
     boolean isopen = false;<br/><br/>

    **// 2. Set master identifier**
    // ModbusCoupler.createModbusCoupler(null);
    // ModbusCoupler.getReference().setMaster(master); I added this in
    // ModbusCoupler.getReference().setMaster(true);
    // ModbusCoupler.getReference().setUnitID(1); 

    **// 3. Setup serial parameters**<br/>
    SerialParameters params = new SerialParameters();<br/>
    params.setPortName("COM1");<br/>
    params.setBaudRate(9600);<br/>
    params.setDatabits(8);<br/>
    params.setParity("None");<br/>
    params.setStopbits(1);<br/>
    params.setEncoding("RTU");<br/>
    params.setEcho(false);<br/>

    System.setProperty("net.wimpi.modbus.debug", "true");<br/>
    **// 4. Open the connection**<br/>
    con = new SerialConnection(params);
    System.out.println("Connection..." + con.toString());
    con.open();

     isopen = con.isOpen();<br/>
     System.out.println("Serial port status..." + isopen);<br/>

    **// 5. Prepare a request<br/>**
    req = new ReadInputRegistersRequest(ref, count);<br/>
    req.setUnitID(unitid);<br/>
    req.setHeadless();<br/>

    **// 6. Prepare a transaction<br/>**
    trans = new ModbusSerialTransaction(con);<br/>
    trans.setRequest(req);<br/>

    **// 7. Execute the transaction repeat times<br/>**
    int k = 0;<br/>
    do { <br/>
    trans.execute();<br/>
    res = (ReadInputRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();<br/>
    for (int n = 0; n < res.getWordCount(); n++) {<br/>
    System.out.println("Word " + n + "=" + res.getRegisterValue(n));<br/>
    }<br/>
    k++;<br/>
    } while (k < repeat);<br/>

    **// 8. Close the connection**<br/>
    con.close();<br/>

    } catch (Exception ex) {<br/>
      ex.printStackTrace();<br/>
    }<br/>
    //}//else<br/>
    }//main

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a method like `Thread.sleep(500)` between `request` and `response` method in `jamod` library. Maybe this kind of error is usually caused by the length of response data.
`jamod` library didn't consider the long size of response data. So, we need to request and wait until all data is received from the serial interface. Ff not, because all data is not received, `CRC` check will fail and cause an error.